# YII2 - Mail always saved as files but not sent despite useFileTransport=false

Tags: yii2, mailer

I am trying to send mails from Yii2 production site, but mails always arrive in runtime/mail folder.

This is the action in the controller:

```
 public function actionTestmail()
 {
   Yii::$app
        ->mailer
        ->compose(['html' => 'courriel-test-html']          
        )
        ->setFrom("user@domain.fr") //->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name . ' robot'])
        ->setTo('me@mydomain.com')
        ->setSubject('Email for test purpose')
        ->send();
     return $this->render('index');
 }
```

**index.php**

```
// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
//defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
//defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

**config/web.php**

```
    'Smtpmail'=>array(
                'class'=>'application.extensions.smtpmail.PHPMailer',
                'useFileTransport' => false,
                'Host'=>"fox.o2switch.net",
                'Username'=>'user@domain.fr',//a valid account 
                'Password'=>'******',//the actual password for the account above
                'Mailer'=>'smtp',
                'Port'=>587,
                'SMTPAuth'=>true, 
                'SMTPSecure' => 'tls',
            ),

or 

      'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'fox.o2switch.net',
                'username' => 'user@domain.fr',
                'password' => '*******',
                'port' => '25',
               // 'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
```

In both cases the result is the same, a file in runtime/mail but no mail actually sent. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually made it out
I had a duplicate in the config that stated "useFileTransport => true,"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the actionTestmail() function like this

```
$mailer = Yii::$app->mailer;
$mailer->useFileTransport = false;
$mailer->compose…
```

It seems that the line

```
'useFileTransport' => false,
```

in the config is useless